# Exclude Jhipster and upgrade Spring Boot from 1.4.0 to 2.0.3

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I am using spring boot 1.4.0 along with jhipster 3.6.1 in my project. I want to upgrade spring boot from 1.4.0 to 2.0.3 but I found some release notes of jhipster according to which it won't support Spring boot 2.0.3.

Can anyone help me out by letting me know if there is any easy and quick way to exclude jhipster from my project.

Answer (score 1):

JHipster 3 won't be updated for Spring Boot 2, only JHipster 5 supports it.

So either you upgrade your project to JHipster 5 using `jhipster upgrade` command or you remove all dependencies from JHipster and you manually upgrade your project.

These dependencies can be of 3 types: BOM for maven dependencies, server library and client library (not required for your use case). For [BOM and server library](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster), the idea is to retrieve the source of the version used by your app and to integrate it into your own git repo so that you can modify it.

Comment: What classes or configuration we can remove to exclude jhipster from project

Comment: Any class from 'io.github.jhipster" package hierarchy but if you do so, your app will no longer compile of course ;) That's why I suggested integrating them into your project.