# Restructure from existing jhipster generated application to spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jhipster

I have jhipster generated spring boot application with spring boot 1.4.0, now I want to upgrade spring boot 2.0.3 only and remove jhipster dependencies.

Can anyone help me to restructure(wanted to rebuild application) my existing application to spring boot application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude Jhipster and upgrade Spring Boot from 1.4.0 to 2.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51702671/exclude-jhipster-and-upgrade-spring-boot-from-1-4-0-to-2-0-3)

Comment: Actually wanted to know the structure of spring boot application

Comment: There's no such thing